# Match text in 2 text files and get information from 1st file and append to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 text files. 1st file contains meta-data information(like font size etc.) of text and 2nd file contains only text. I need to match text between 2 files, take meta-data information from 1st file and prepend it in the 2nd file. For example,

**File A Data:**

```
[Base Font : PSJEPX+Muli-Light, Font Size : 7.5, Font Weight : 300.0]We are not satisfied with our 2018 results. We have the global footprint, assets and team to 
[Base Font : SVTVFR+Muli-Light, Font Size : 7.5, Font Weight : 300.0] 

[Base Font : PSJEPX+Muli-Light, Font Size : 7.5, Font Weight : 300.0]perform better. We have made a number of changes to position for sustainable growth.
New line that does not start with square brackets.
[Base Font : SVTVFR+Muli-SemiBold, Font Size : 8.1, Font Weight : 600.0]Innovation
```

**File B Data :**

```
We are not satisfied with our 2018 results. We have the global footprint, assets and team to perform better. We have made a number of changes to position for sustainable growth.
New line that does not start with square brackets.

Innovation
```

**Expected Output :**

```
[Base Font : PSJEPX+Muli-Light, Font Size : 7.5, Font Weight : 300.0]We are not satisfied with our 2018 results. We have the global footprint, assets and team to perform better. We have made a number of changes to position for sustainable growth.
New line that does not start with square brackets.

[Base Font : SVTVFR+Muli-SemiBold, Font Size : 8.1, Font Weight : 600.0]Innovation
```

So, basically, the metadata from "File A" must be attached to "File B" only when there is a change in metadata information.

**My Approach :**

```
 def readB(x):
     with open(File B) as resultFile:
         for line in resultFile:
             if x in line:
                 print(x)

def readA():
    with open(File A) as bondNumberFile:
        for line in bondNumberFile:
            readB(line)

readA()
```

My problem is, I am not sure how to take the metadata information from File A and attach it to File B. Also, my code is not able to handle the metadata information(inside square brackets) while matching text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below program. This program first reads `filea` and creates a dictionary of style and lines, then reads `fileb` line by line to match and pick style from dictionary, and writes it to `filec`.

```py
import re
table={}
with open("filea.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            parts=re.findall("^(\[.*?\])?(.*)$",line)[0]
            if parts[0] in table:
                table[parts[0]]+=parts[1]
            else:
                table[parts[0]]=parts[1]
with open("fileb.txt","r") as f, open("filec.txt","w") as f1:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            for i in table:
                if line.strip() in table[i]:
                    f1.write(i+line)
                    break
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            f1.write(line)
```

**Output**

```
[Base Font : PSJEPX+Muli-Light, Font Size : 7.5, Font Weight : 300.0]We are not satisfied with our 2018 results. We have the global footprint, assets and team to perform better. We have made a number of changes to position for sustainable growth.
New line that does not start with square brackets.

[Base Font : SVTVFR+Muli-SemiBold, Font Size : 8.1, Font Weight : 600.0]Innovation
```

Comment: Hi @Liju, Thank you for the quick response. But can you please explain the logic. Also, at line6 (parts=re.findall("^(\[.*?\])(.*)$",line)[0]), I am getting list index out of range. Not sure, but possibly because not all the lines in my actual scenario starts with "[". I have incorporated that scenario as well in my question.

Comment: @ChampRJ I have updated the code above with your new scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Liju ... With some modification, I was able to use it for my case. Modification was done for my other scenario but your answer works for input mentioned in the question.